# Web API 2 DelegateHandler Not Invoked When IdentityServer3 Implemented

Tags: c#, identityserver3, .net-4.6

I am having a very weird scenario when trying to add a custom  `DelegatingHandler`. The `SendAsync` gets invoked. Up to this point, everything is happy with life.

However, as soon as I add Authentication using IdentityServer3, all of my `DelegatingHandlers` are ignored. `SendAsync()` is not invoked.

The `DelegatingHandler`:

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 
            // log request body
        string requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Trace.WriteLine(requestBody);

        // let other handlers process the request
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // once response body is ready, log it
        var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Trace.WriteLine(responseBody);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The `startup.cs`

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = Globals.TokenAuthenticationAuthority,
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "scope1", "scope2", "scope3" }
        });

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

The `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LogRequestAndResponseHandler());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

After digging and playing around, I found that the line that breaks is the

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

But I just dont understand why. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it get through to the Controller? Also, are you calling `WebApiConfig.Register` anywhere?

Comment: It does get through the controller and processes the request as normal. The WebApiConfig.Register is called in the Global.asax.cs @mdickin

Comment: Does `WebApiConfig.Register()` get called before or after `Configuration()` in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: `public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }` Thats the Global.asax.cs The Startup.cs code is at the top. @mdickin

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If `Configuration()` gets called after `WebApiConfig.Register()`, then it's overwriting the global `HttpConfiguration`. Can you put breakpoints in to see the order of calls?

Comment: `Configuration()` gets called after 'WebApiConfig.Register()' @mdickin

Answer (score 0):

From the comment chain on the question

> Configuration() gets called after 'WebApiConfig.Register()'

This is the problem. The `Configuration()` method in `Startup.cs` creates a new `HttpConfiguration` and passes it to `.UseWebApi()`. This effectively undoes everything that `WebApiConfig.Register()` does, as it adds filters, message handlers, etc. to the `HttpConfiguration` that is passed in.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Change `var config = new HttpConfiguration();` in `Startup.cs` to `var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`
2. Call `Startup.Configuration()` before `WebApiConfig.Register()` and be sure to pass in the new `HttpConfiguration`